# LSTM with changing batch size while training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, batchsize

I'm trying to build an LSTM on app-log data from different users. I have one big dataframe consisting of stacked app records of the users, so for example the first 1500 rows are for user 1, the following 500 for user 2 etc. I'm now wondering if it is possible to train the LSTM in such a way that the weights are updated after each user which would mean changing the batch size after each update. For a better understanding: I want the LSTM to first take all records of user 1 which are 1500 rows and make an update of weights after processing them, after that it should take the 500 rows of user 2 and should make an update of weights after processing them etc.

I'm building the LSTM with Keras.

Is there a possibility to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Is pytorch acceptable?

Comment: I have never worked with it but if you can suggest a solution for my problem in PyTorch I would consider switching

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific application scenario, but I'm assuming it's time series forecasting.

Build the LSTM model:

```py
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.num_directions = 1
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_size, self.hidden_size, self.num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)

    def forward(self, input_seq):
        h_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        # print(input_seq.size())
        seq_len = input_seq.shape[1]
        # input(batch_size, seq_len, input_size)
        input_seq = input_seq.view(self.batch_size, seq_len, self.input_size)
        # output(batch_size, seq_len, num_directions * hidden_size)
        output, _ = self.lstm(input_seq, (h_0, c_0))
        # print('output.size=', output.size())
        # print(self.batch_size * seq_len, self.hidden_size)
        output = output.contiguous().view(self.batch_size * seq_len, self.hidden_size)  # (5 * 30, 64)
        pred = self.linear(output)  # pred()
        # print('pred=', pred.shape)
        pred = pred.view(self.batch_size, seq_len, -1)
        pred = pred[:, -1, :]
        return pred
```

You can use DataLoader to process data from different users with batch sizes of different sizes to get data sets of multiple users.

Like this:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

Dtr = DataLoader(dataset=train, batch_size=B, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
Dte = DataLoader(dataset=test, batch_size=B, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
```

Then, we start training:

```py
for t in range(len(users)):
    # change batch size
    b = batchsizes[t]   # Store batch_size of each user in batchsizes
    model = LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, batch_size=b).to(device)
    if t != 0:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(LSTM_PATH)['model'])
    model.train()
    Dtr = Dtrs[t]  # Store train data of each user in Dtrs
    for i in range(epochs):
        cnt = 0
        for (seq, label) in Dtr:
            cnt += 1
            seq = seq.to(device)
            label = label.to(device)
            y_pred = model(seq)
            loss = loss_function(y_pred, label)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            if cnt % 100 == 0:
                print('epoch', i, ':', cnt - 100, '~', cnt, loss.item())
    # Save the current user's model after training
    state = {'model': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
    torch.save(state, LSTM_PATH)
```

I'm sorry that the above code is not working directly, because I don't know your data situation, so I just provide you with a general framework.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with this solution. When I'm right it will build one model for each user? I'm trying to build one model which incrementally includes the information of different users and yes it is a multiclass classification time-series prediction

Comment: Instead of building a model for every user, all users use the same model. When a user finishes training the model with his own batch size, the model will be saved, and then the next user will load the model and continue training the model with his own batch size.

Comment: Great, then I misunderstood your code and you did exactly what I was looking for. I will try it!